# MySQL sly select

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

Can not understand how to make an select:
table structure:

```
id name value date
1 ivan    2    2010-01-01
2 ivan    3    2010-05-08
3 ivan    1    2009-04-14
4 sasha   2    2011-11-11
5 sasha   9    2012-04-04
```

How to get?:

```
name value(in last time)
ivan  3
sasha 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work

```
select f.name, f.value, f.date
from (
   select id,name,max(date) as dat from tableName group by name
) as x inner join tableName as f on f.name = x.name and f.date = x.dat;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, but should work:

```
SELECT
    name,
    MAX(value)
FROM
    structure
GROUP BY
    name
```

Comment: `SELECT name, MAX(value) ...`

Comment: name and MAX(value) not an one row

Comment: @Oleg: Ah, you want the last value per name (ordered by date). That's a `[greatest-n-per-group]` query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, value FROM table ORDER BY date DESC
```

thats what i understand from your current description so far.

Comment: Sorry to all!
My case is two table.
I think its work equally.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
    MAX(value),
    name
FROM
    Table
GROUP BY
    name
```